# PHP int to date problem

Tags: php, date, youtube-api

Take a look on the code below:

```
$t=77;
date("H:i:s", $t);
```

It returns

```
21:01:17
```

The correct result, of course, should be something like 00:01:17.

The $t value indeed is a value in seconds returned by the YouTube [GData](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GData) API, `trought($videoEntry->getVideoDuration())`.

How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

date is timezone specific. You need to set it to GMT to get the results you want.

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$t=77;
echo date("H:i:s", $t);
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to date() is a unix timestamp - in other words it is a number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970, adjusted to what PHP is set to for a timezone (can be set with date_default_timezone_set).

Answer (score -1):

Try to set GMT timezone.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Comment: Isn't London on a different time than GMT some parts of the year?

Comment: Setting to Europe/London returns 01:01:17. See solution below.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you getting values in second, then you should use mktime function then it will give correct result. For eg.:

```
$t=77;
echo date("H:i:s", mktime(0,0,$t));
```

Comment: Hey. The `mktime` function creates a timestamp - the number of seconds since `1970-01-01`- and using it with only a seconds value simply creates a timestamp for today, at that specific time. E.g. `2009-12-01 00:01:17` *(using GMT)*. Which, if you are only interested in the time values, changes nothing. What you posted is effectively equivalent to `$t=77; echo date("H:i:s", $t);`.